# The given value is not suitable for child module variable "aws_auth_user_map" : list of object required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to load values to below terraform variable but I am getting The given value is not suitable for child module variable The given value is not suitable for child module variable "aws_auth_user_map" defined at modules/cluster/variables.tf:139,1-29: list of object required.

```
variable "aws_auth_user_map" {
  type = list(object({
    userarn  = string
    username = string
    groups   = list(string)
  }))
  default     = []
  description = "A list of mappings from aws user arns to kubernetes users, and their groups"
}
```

and this is how I am adding default values.

```
{userarn="arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:user/pXXl.brXXd", username="XX.XX", groups=["admin", "dev"]}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Your value is an `object` that appears correct for the nested type, but is not a `list(object))`. If you add a list constructor syntax `[]` around your value, does that fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `default` value should be a `list`:

```
variable "aws_auth_user_map" {
  type = list(object({
    userarn  = string
    username = string
    groups   = list(string)
  }))
  default     = [{userarn="arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:user/pXXl.brXXd", username="XX.XX", groups=["admin", "dev"]}]
  description = "A list of mappings from aws user arns to kubernetes users, and their groups"
}
```